# HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error on wordpress

Tags: php, asp.net, wordpress, .htaccess, iis-7.5

am new here - I have been having problems with this $%%$%$ IIS7.5 I have finished developing a wordpress site on my localhost using xampp - so I thought this was gonna be business as usual just copy files to remote- change config and dump sql - boy was I wrong! I think I have done everything I know to do and am still getting this annoying HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error

#### This is what I get each time,When I am trying to access the site:

HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error

The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.

Detailed Error Information

Module
FastCgiModule

Notification
ExecuteRequestHandler

Handler
PHP_via_FastCGI

Error Code

```
0x00000000
```

Requested URL
http://mysite.com:80/index.php

Physical Path

```
E:\HostingSpaces\xxxxxxxxx\mysite.com\wwwroot\index.php
```

Logon Method
Anonymous

Logon User
Anonymous

Most likely causes: •IIS received the request; however, an internal error occurred during the processing of the request. The root cause of this error depends on which module handles the request and what was happening in the worker process when this error occurred.
•IIS was not able to access the web.config file for the Web site or application. This can occur if the NTFS permissions are set incorrectly.
•IIS was not able to process configuration for the Web site or application.
•The authenticated user does not have permission to use this DLL.
•The request is mapped to a managed handler but the .NET Extensibility Feature is not installed.

Things you can try: •Ensure that the NTFS permissions for the web.config file are correct and allow access to the Web server's machine account.
•Check the event logs to see if any additional information was logged.
•Verify the permissions for the DLL.
•Install the .NET Extensibility feature if the request is mapped to a managed handler.
•Create a tracing rule to track failed requests for this HTTP status code. For more information about creating a tracing rule for failed requests, click here.

Links and More Information This error means that there was a problem while processing the request. The request was received by the Web server, but during processing a fatal error occurred, causing the 500 error.
View more information »

Microsoft Knowledge Base Articles:

```
•294807
```

Please can anyone just tell me precisely what to do,I cant take it anymore.. please help me.

So my case is hopeless - i cant be helped?

Comment: Post what is on your `web.config` file please

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="wordpress" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Answer (score 0):

IIS server is not equal to Apache. It uses another type of configs. I think your problem in the `web.config` file or related to permissions. Your question isn't so subjective. You need to localize problem and describe here more detailed information. Now your question looks like this: "I have PHP application on IIS that doesn't work. I tested it on my xampp. Where is problem?". There are a lot of problems that you can have here...

Comment: Thanks for your response - honestly i don't know where else to look this is my first time using a this - i just don't know what to do-

Comment: You can switch to another server with apache or study how to work with IIS

Comment: can you please help me out? if i supply you the ftp details

Comment: how do i know what permission to set and which folder?

Answer (score 0):

I has same problem with php 5.6 on iis 6 (windows server 2012 r2)

You should ensure the VC++11 runtime is installed (for me it's [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2012 Update 4](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679&wa=wsignin1.0))

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the connection string mismatch,check your connection string.

Comment: It would help if you could provide some additional information such as references or examples. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

"500 - Internal server error" error message when a user tries to access your Apache or Lighttpd based dynamic php application 
Generally, to solve this problem you need to take help of log files located at following location:
=> /var/log/message
=> /var/log/httpd/error_logs (/var/log/lighttpd/error_log or /var/log/httpd/error_log)
This error only occurs because of web server software. However after looking through logs you may not find many details. This problem may be caused by:

A malformed php cgi script
An invalid directive in an .htaccess or other config file
Limitation imposed by file system and server software (for example php log file size set to 10Mb)
Missing php.ini (or cannot read php.ini file)

Comment: please how do i view this log where?